# Spark gives different results when node count changes

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

In our implementation of the Eclat algorithm on Spark (Java), algorithm gives the correct result on single node. But when the node count is increased, algorithm gives wrong results.

Specifically, it gives the different results on this line:

```
JavaPairRDD<List<String>, List<Long>> reduced = rdd.reduceByKey((x,y)->Lists.newArrayList(Sets.intersection(Sets.newHashSet(x), Sets.newHashSet(y))));
```

We thought that it is due to the partitioning. What could be the reason, and how could it be fixed? Thanks.

Comment: could you post some sample input/output & point out where its differing?

Comment: It is just as in FP Growth:
The input is list of transactions such as:
[a b c d]  
[a c d ] 
[e]  

[a b d]  


And the output is frequent itemsets:  
[a, b]  
[a, d]  
  
Multinode and single node cases gives different count of frequent itemsets.